# convert HTTP request code to HTTPS request code

Tags: asp.net, xml, http, web-services, https

I have got following code witch are sending xml file on HTTP protocol and getting response back as xml file from webserver and its working fine with HTTP protocol, but now i need to send such a XML file to HTTPS protocol (not http) and need to get response as xml file from it. the code to send xml file and get response from HTTP is :

```
    string targetUri = "http://www.hostelspoint.com/xml/xml.php"; /*this will be like: "https://www.hostelspoint.com/xml/xml.php"*/
    System.Xml.XmlDocument reqDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    reqDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\getdetail.xml"));
    string formParameterName = "OTA_request";
    string xmlData = reqDoc.InnerXml;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
    string sendString = formParameterName + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(xmlData);
    //string sendString =  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(xmlData);

    byte[] byteStream;
    byteStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendString);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteStream.LongLength;

    using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        writer.Write(byteStream, 0, (int)request.ContentLength);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string respStr = "";
    if (request.HaveResponse)
    {
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        {
            StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            respStr = respReader.ReadToEnd(); // get the xml result in the string object  

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(respStr);
            Label1.Text = doc.InnerXml.ToString();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be much difference in your code, as HTTP or HTTPS differs only in transport level, not in application level. 
What may become a problem here is, if the server certificate used in the targetUri is trusted on your server. In this case the HTTPS identity cannot be verified.

Comment: what i am understanding from u is that: you are saying that if we want to work with HTTPS instead of HTTP then only URL in above code will be changed to HTTPS instead of HTTP. otherwise their is no need to do change in code right?

Comment: Yes, as long as you trust the HTTPS certificate from the server.